# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement engine (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for engine

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-engine

I am trying to import `matlab.engine`

I keep getting  -

```
        cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 385, in run
        File "<string>", line 156, in _create_path_list
      RuntimeError: MATLAB R2023a installation not found. Install to default location, or add <matlabroot>/bin/maca64 to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, where <matlabroot> is the root of a MATLAB R2023a installation.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matlabengine
Failed to build matlabengine
ERROR: Could not build wheels for matlabengine, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have the matlab app installed in the default location.

I have tried `import matlab.engine`
I have tried `python -r pip install matlabengine`
I am using Python 3.9

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html)? The PyPI installation only works with the latest MATLAB version I think. Maybe you do t have R2023a?

Comment: I just downloaded it. It's the latest version.